# Referencing a figure in the text before the figure

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I'm wanting to reference a figure, but I know that the usual way of doing it:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!] 
\centering
\includegraphics{image.png}\\
\label{fig:fig1}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

then using `\ref{fig:fig1}` in the text only allows you to reference a figure when the reference in the text comes after the figure placement. Is there a way of doing it so that I can reference a figure earlier in the text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Actually, you need a `\caption` as well, the above won't give any figure number to reference. However, as Romain says, `\ref` works whether it is placed either before or after the element that is referenced. Edit: And that `\\ ` after `\includegraphics` is sort of pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same. You will have to compile your file two time and the reference will be good.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reference my figure in the text preceding my figure by placing the \label command *after* \caption in the figure.